# Does SignalR Java client supports TLS 1.2?

Tags: java, android, ssl, signalr

In an Android project, I'd like to use SignalR, and protect the communication. Right now the test server is set up on Azure (SignalR Service + App Service). Azure doesn't support TLS 1.3 yet, and probably the final server we'll use in production too will have only TLS 1.2.

Is the Java client for SignalR supports TLS 1.2? If so, how can I enable it?

When I change the hub URL to starts with `https`, I get an error:

```
Connection failed to start: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x7c42a3fac0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
    error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER (external/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:239 0x7c405330ab:0x00000000)
```

I found that the [old SignalR Java client](https://github.com/SignalR/java-client/blob/f226631da562cfaacbe8b16d5a9ecbf8205e7c99/signalr-client-sdk/src/microsoft/aspnet/signalr/client/Connection.java#L31) supported only TLS 1.3, but this repository is archived, and [in the new client](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/tree/master/src/SignalR/clients/java/signalr/src/main/java/com/microsoft/signalr) I can't find any limitation on the protocol version.

If TLS 1.2 is supported in the newer version, why do I get this error?

The phone I'm testing on has Android API level 25. Relevant parts of the Gradle configuration:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16 // Also tried with 20+
        targetSdkVersion 29
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.microsoft.signalr:signalr:3.0.0'
}
```

Comment: It isn't up to SignalR. It is up to the SSL support inside Java.

Comment: The Java version that the Android version includes and I tried should support TLS 1,2. What else do I need?